# Numeric double integration

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numerical-methods

I've made a simple program for numerically aproximating double integral, which accepts that the bounds of the inner integral are functions:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def double_integral(func, limits, res=1000):
        t = time.clock()
        t1 = time.clock()
        t2 = time.clock()
        s = 0
        a, b = limits[0], limits[1]
        outer_values = np.linspace(a, b, res)
        c_is_func = callable(limits[2])
        d_is_func = callable(limits[3])
        for y in outer_values:
            if c_is_func:
                c = limits[2](y)
            else:
                c = limits[2]
            if d_is_func:
                d = limits[3](y)
            else:
                d = limits[3]
            dA = ((b - a) / res) * ((d - c) / res)
            inner_values = np.linspace(c, d, res)
            for x in inner_values:
                t2 = time.clock() - t2
                s += func(x, y) * dA
            t1 = time.clock() - t1
         t = time.clock() - t
         return s, t, t1 / res, t2 / res**2
```

This is, however, terribly slow. When res=1000, such that the integral is a sum of a million parts, it takes about 5 seconds to run, but the answer is only correct to about the 3rd decimal in my experience. Is there any way to speed this up?

The code i am running to check the integral is

```
def f(x, y):
    if (4 - y**2 - x**2) < 0:
        return 0              #This is to avoid taking the root of negarive #'s
    return np.sqrt(4 - y**2 - x**2)

def c(y):
    return np.sqrt(2 * y - y**2)

def d(y):
    return np.sqrt(4 - y**2)
# b d
# S S f(x,y) dx dy
# a c
a, b, = 0, 2
print(double_integral(f, [a, b, c, d]))
```

The integral is eaqual to 16/9

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) Don't even *think* of the clock in inner loops. Have a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). Do you know [SciPy integrate](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU9PGQtLrZAhXD2KQKHU0qBdQQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fscipy%2Freference%2Ftutorial%2Fintegrate.html&usg=AOvVaw0-t5Pcws-lLU6KuxcmVGjF)?

Comment: You really ought to include all your `import` statements; I'm assuming at the very least you have `import numpy as np` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `numpy`, use `numpy` properly. Inestead of

```
for x in inner_values:
    s += func(x, y) * dA
```

use the more idiomatic, and much faster

```
s += dA * np.sum(func(inner_values, y))
```

Note: this requires rewriting `f` as

```
return np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, 4 - y**2 - x**2))
```

so it can accept an array as an input. This does not reduce accuracy, but brings time down to a much more accaptable `.04` seconds for a 100x improvement. The takeaway here is **Numpy is not magic. It provides quick vectorization**.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by greybeard in comments, double integration is available in SciPy as [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad). This has a similar interface to the code in the post:

> `scipy.integrate.dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args=(), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)`
>
> Compute a double integral.
>
> Return the double (definite) integral of `func(y, x)` from `x = a..b` and `y = gfun(x)..hfun(x)`.

The differences are (i) `func` takes its arguments in the other order; (ii) the lower and upper boundaries must be specified by callables (but this is not a limitation because you can specify a constant boundary \$y=c\$ with the function `lambda x:c`); (iii) there are arguments for absolute and relative tolerance of the result.

So for the example problem you'd write:

```
import numpy as np

def f(y, x):
    return np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, 4 - y**2 - x**2))

def c(y):
    return np.sqrt(2 * y - y**2)

def d(y):
    return np.sqrt(4 - y**2)
```

and then:

```
>>> import scipy.integrate
>>> scipy.integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 2, c, d)
(1.7777777777777706, 1.3374816809630374e-09)
```

(The second result is an estimate of the absolute error in the first result, though an over-estimate in this case.)

Comment: I thought that might be the problem, but as you might notice, this integral is symmetrical. f(x,y)=f(y,x). I sent my code to a friend, he ran it as is and got the right answer. I am starting to believe an exorcism might be my only way out.

Comment: So i have been using Anaconda, but tried running it in vanilla python (the exact same code) and got the right answer...

Answer (score -2):

For a function strickly growing.
Between a and b
Recursively Search at x interssection point between the line a and b and compare the delta y if too much you you add the point c and check the intersection.
After that you have to sum the trapezoid sirfaces